# Convert string to dictionary key value - split issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to convert a string to key value pair for testing purposes. The issue I have is that when I split the string, the value can be null in rare occasions

For example:

```
"Sent On\r\n2021-01-31 09:18:42"
"Priority\r\nLow"
```

When I use the following code it works fine for all records except when value is null. There will always be a key

```
Dictionary<string, string> details = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 foreach (var row in Rows)
            {
                var text = row.Text.Replace("\r\n", ",");
                var splitText = text.IndexOf(",");
                var key = text.Substring(0, splitText);
                var value = text.Substring(splitText + 1);

                details.Add(key, value);
            }
            return details;
```

The issue is when the text is like this and I only have a key and no value. I cant split the text either by '\r\n' as it doesnt have a value

```
"Read On"
```

how can I modify my code to check if this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
foreach (var row in Rows)
{
    var parts = row.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var key = parts[0];
    var value = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : null;
    details.Add(key, value);
}
```

Or even this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> details =
    Rows
        .Select(row => row.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : null);
```